# Django ORM: Get verbose_name of field via filter lookup

Tags: django, django-orm

I can query my model with `MyModel.objects.filter(othermodel__nr='foo')`.

This works fine.

I would like to get the **verbose_name** of the field.

Example:

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    nr=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Number')
```

In above example it easy since I can access `OtherModel`, but I would like to do it generic.

How to get the verbose name of a field which is used in "key" here?

`MyModel.objects.filter(**{key: value})`

I search a method which resolves the double underscore. In this example "othermodel__nr" to (for example) "Number".

## Update

In above example I know that the referenced model is `OtherModel`. But I search a solution which works for any strings. For example like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(**{str_containing_three_double_underscores: 'foo'})
```

I search for:

```
get_verbose_name(str_containing_three_double_underscores) --> MyVerboseName
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To handle your comment to @MoisésHiraldo I think it is better to do this in context of the model.

```
from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

def get_verbose_name(model, lookup):
    # will return first non relational field's verbose_name in lookup
    for part in lookup.split(LOOKUP_SEP):
        try:
            f = model._meta.get_field(part)
        except FieldDoesNotExist:
            # check if field is related
            for f in model._meta.related_objects:
                if f.get_accessor_name() == part:
                    break
            else:
                raise ValueError("Invalid lookup string")
        if f.is_relation:
            model = f.related_model
            continue
        return force_text(f.verbose_name)

get_verbose_name(MyModel, str_containing_three_double_underscores)
```

Comment: I see. You parse it with `lookup.split(LOOKUP_SEP)`. Looks good ... and works. Thank you. I found a small part to simplify it. I will update your answer, ok?

Comment: @guettli `LOOKUP_SEP` is `__` . It just more DRY this way))

Comment: this was not part of the question. And it was duplicate code. I want to see the important part immediately. Don't get me wrong. Thank you very much for this great method. I had written one myself, but this more complicated and failed on some lookups. Yours works.

Comment: @guettli understood. You are welcome. Also you can improve it a little by combining my answer and MoisésHiraldo's for cases when you don't have a model.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev - What is ** str_containing_three_double_underscores**? Calling the function raises error `name 'str_containing_three_double_underscores' is not defined`. Any remedy?

Comment: @user12379095 It is your argument: `get_verbose_name(MyModel, 'field__second_level_field')`

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev - Just after I had posted my first comment, I went to the beginning of the question and could see it is about the field reference. I am sorry, but for a model **my_model** with a field `field1  = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Mec Name')` how do I pass the argument? Could you please clarify?

Comment: `get_verbose_name(my_model, 'field1')`. But you don't have to do this with this function. This function is required for cases when you have FK fields. You can just do `my_model._meta.get_field('field1').verbose_name`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like this, assuming `filter_key` always ends with "model__field":

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

def get_verbose_name(filter_key):
    model = filter_key.split("__")[-2]
    field = filter_key.split("__")[-1]
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=model)
    return content_type.model_class()._meta.get_field(field).verbose_name
```

Comment: Yes, this should work in most cases. AFAIK model names are not unique. There could be two models with the same name (coming from a different app) ....

Comment: There could also be the case that the foreign key name in the filter (which comes from the field name) doesn't match the actual model name. To make something completely generic you could split `filter_key` and start inspecting fields and following relations from the fist item (eg. `model._meta.get_field("fk_field").related_model`).

Answer (score 1):

recursive way

```py
from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP

def get_verbose_name(model_class, field_name: str) -> str:
    if LOOKUP_SEP in field_name:
        rel_model_name, field_name = field_name.split(LOOKUP_SEP, 1)
        rel_model = model_class._meta.get_field(rel_model_name).related_model
        return get_verbose_name(rel_model, field_name)
    return model_class._meta.get_field(field_name).verbose_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need ORM filtering for this. If I got your question correctly, you already know the class which you want the field's verbose name, right?

If so, you could use `ModelName._meta.get_field('field_name').verbose_name` to get it directly, no need to use ORM at all.

Comment: thank you for this hint. The question was not 100% clear. I updated it. Is the question clear now?

Comment: I see, if you have the model and field name as strings, I guess that splitting the filter and using ContentType as @moisés-hiraldo said is the way to go.